# what do I do if linux doesn't create the var / log / journal directory despite rebooting with systemctl?

Tags: systemd, logs, reboot, systemd-journald, systemctl

I need help, the journal service was not configured correctly with systemctl restart systemd-journald.service, since I want to protect journal files with storage = persistent,but linux does not create the / var / log / journal directory

Answer (score -1):

uncomment or add "Storage=persistent" in /etc/systemd/journald.conf